# Repeatedly "trying to add a new helper tool" on each restart for same application(s)

Tags: macos, mac, install

Every time I restart my computer, it tries to "add a new helper tool". For instance I have to reinstall shell commands in Atom on every restart, and it prompts with the "An update is ready to install."  But I see this same issue with other programs too.

Atom installs `/usr/local/bin/atom` -- but then when I restart it's gone.

I get the same thing from MAMP that it "wants to make changes".

And Slack gives me the same thing as Atom on every restart:

[image: Slack is trying to add a new helper tool.]

> An update is ready to install. Slack is trying to add a new helper tool.
>
> Enter an administrator's name and password to allow this.
>
> Add Helper

Let me know what other information I can give.

Comment: Removing and reinstalling the app should also fix it.

Answer (score 35):

Try changing the ownership of Atom.app. In my case, Atom.app was found in /Applications, and ownership was:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 1699963712  365896978    102 Dec  8 12:48 Atom.app
```

I ran the following command (`-R` means operate recursively):

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:wheel /Applications/Atom.app
```

This changes the owner to the currently logged-in user and the group to `wheel`.

In my case, any program with ownership of `root` or the numeric code listed above would have a popup a few seconds after opening. Changing ownership of the .app directory corrected the behavior and I don't see it anymore.

I found the information at [this site](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/5l5crw/slack_is_trying_to_install_a_new_helper_tool/).

**Note**: on newer Mac OS versions, like 13, you could get `operation not permitted` errors. To remedy that, be sure to enable Full Disk Access for Terminal from System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access, and try again.

Comment: Kept on getting `operation not permitted` and enabling Full Disk Access didn't help. So I accomplished this via UI by using the Apple recommendation https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac#:~:text=Change%20an%20item's%20owner&text=If%20the%20new%20owner's%20name,%E2%80%9CMake%20__%20the%20owner.%E2%80%9D

Comment: I'm not sure "allow writing of shared application code" is a good idea...
You're essentially advocating bypassing the system security.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution: run any OS X atom-based apps such as Slack or Signal out of your `~/Applications` directory.

The root of the problem is that these apps were installed system-wide via a mechanism like Homebrew, or manually by you and owned by root. So the easy/quick workaround is to copy them to a place where your **current** user has write access:

```
killall Slack && rsync -av --delete /Applications/Slack.app/ ~/Applications/Slack.app/ && open ~/Applications/Slack.app
```

(if you prefer the Finder, drag and drop instead)

Now when the atom application's built-in update mechanism tries to write to its files, it can! No more annoying pop-up windows!

Comment: Got `The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10827 "kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing" UserInfo={_LSLine=3691, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}` after the `open ~/Applications/Slack.app` step. Ultimately went with [the answer with more votes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271123/14117) and it worked.

Comment: `The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10827 "kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing" UserInfo={_LSLine=3762, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}
`

Comment: @alper was it also Slack that was broken for you?

Comment: I wonder if my command was not clearing out old Slack.app state. I added `--delete` above in case that was the problem. @MariusButuc can you try it again with the updated command above?

Comment: @EdwardTeach No sir I was using ` CleanMyMac X`. Why are you using `rsync -av --delete` can't we just carry the app to the location we can by carry and drop

Comment: @alper yes drag and drop ought to work just as well. I used `rsync` because it allows me to paste in a single command. No other reason :)

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the application and manually dragging it into the Applications folder also worked for me.

Comment: The application is already there, with my user wielding Read/Write permissions, but still would ask for administrative privileges to add helper tools. I am talking about VS Code however.

Answer (score 0):

I had this annoying issue with Skype. The solution was:

1. Enable root on MAC:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012
2. `cd /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools`
3. `su root`   This step requires login with admin privileges
4. `rm com.skype.Helper`

Comment: Could you just run `sudo rm /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.skype.Helper` without enabling root?  Your answer is helpful though.

Comment: Enabling the root user on a Mac can open major security holes, especially for end users. If you need to use the root user by command line, I recommend using an administrator user, typing `sudo su` to switch to root. It will ask for a password.

Comment: For me the file was named com.skypinstaller...

Comment: `sudo rm ...` will ask for a password too not sure why it seems less secure? @juniorRubyist

Comment: This did not work on my end