# NordVPN wants to install a helper tool prompt at every restart

Tags: macos, permission, vpn

Every time I startup my mac, I boot up NordVPN and it always seems to give this prompt, which it never did so often before:

[image: NordVPN Being a PITA]

I'm on macOS 13.6 (22G120), and I have tried removing every file related to NordVPN prior to reinstalling it. If I remember correctly, this was the result of the application updating. One update has occurred since and has not fixed this.

Dismissing the prompt and attempting to connect will just bring up the same prompt again, so I have to enter my password. When installing, I used the `.pkg` instead of the App Store (I do not have any accounts), and during installation, the `.pkg` needed permissions to read my downloads folder (where the installer was). App version is `8.10.4`.

`ls -lr` shows the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x@  3 me  wheel        96 Oct 12 07:46 NordVPN.app
```

Have tried the first two solutions listed here, but it does not seem to work:
[Repeatedly "trying to add a new helper tool" on each restart for same application(s)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267685/repeatedly-trying-to-add-a-new-helper-tool-on-each-restart-for-same-applicatio)

The only "solution" I have not tried yet is setting my password to one character.

Comment: Changed my password to 'a' as a temporarily solution. NordVPN still shows the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Download NordVPN from Nord's website instead of the App Store. I think that should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/344163)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are incorrect. I did answer the question. Apple's software is dumb and installing Nord VPN from their app store causes an issue where a password is repeatedly requested. Instead, just download and install Nord VPN from Nord's website, like I said, and you won't have the issue. It has worked for me. I have tried alternating between the different versions multiple times and gotten the same result.

Comment: Your initial answer was just instructions without explaining why your answer would work. Your comment **now** provides details that would help a user understand why they should attempt your solution. It would be beneficial to other users if you could [edit] that information into your answer.